# When I type any \usepackage{} I get the error \RequirePackage

Tags: errors

The problem is with any `\usepackage{}` that I type and it is not specific. The error is this:

```
! LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help....
```

Comment: We need some more context here...

Comment: It seems that you load package before `\documntclass{...}` ...

Comment: If I remember correctly this error happens with a wrong placement of `\ExecuteOptions` or `\ProcessOptions` in the package 'preamble'

Answer (score 4):

The package you are loading has

```
\RequirePackage
```

or

```
\usepackage
```

(which is the same thing)

after

```
\DeclareOption
```

but before that option has been processed with

```
\ProcessOptions
```

That is not allowed.